# how to use jQuery plugin (semantic-ui) in angularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

I use semantic-ui in my project, the pulgin is checkbox
someone say if use jQ plugin, you must use it in angular directive
but it doesn't work

the checkbox of semantic-ui setting in semantic-ui API document, you must set this to init checkbox

```
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
```

I try to change it to angular like this:

**app.html**

```
<div class="ui animate list">
  <div class="item ui toggle checkbox" todo-checkbox ng-repeat="item in day track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label ng-bind="item.content"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is directive in angularjs file

```
todoApp.directive('todoCheckbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $(elem).checkbox();
    }
  };
});
```

but it doesn't work in my project.  Why?

Comment: @StanislavKralin your edits would be better received if you explained, in your edit summary, *why* you're removing the tag. It's obvious from the diff that you are remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. `elem` is the element of the directive. In this case it is

```
<div class="item ui toggle checkbox" todo-checkbox ng-repeat="item in day track by $index">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label ng-bind="item.content"></label>
</div>
```

Now, if we use `find` to help us locate the input field within the `elem`, then we can select the input field and run the `checkbox` method.

```
todoApp.directive('todoCheckbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      angular.forEach(elem.find( "input" ), function(inputField) {
        inputField.checkbox();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Your message was cut-off. Can you post again? I'm happy to help solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work with your method, in officlal API, the `checkbox()` is bind on `.ui.checkbox` element, I think the problem is not which elem to bind

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to my code. Try it out. Adjustment below. `elem.find( "input" )[0].checkbox();`

Comment: after the adjustment will an error code，`TypeError: elem.find(...)[0].checkbox is not a function`

Comment: I try this, if I don't use `ng-repeat`, `elem.checkbox()` can work normal,but if I use `ng-repeat`,it can't work,I think this is the main reason

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. In the updated answer, I'm looping through all of the checkboxes found and initiating the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but you should be able to just move the `todo-checkbox` to the `input` tag (same with the semantic ui specific attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
angular.element(elem).checkbox();
```

instead of

```
$(elem).checkbox();
```